# App no longer goes into background when an update is installed

Tags: ios, ios8

In iOS7 when prompted to install an update to an app, if the user pressed install the app would immediately close and the install would begin. As far as I can tell, in iOS 8 this behavior has been changed to not start the update process until the user manually closes the app.

For my app's purposes, I expect this to cause confusion to the user who is now expecting the app to update, but the app just sits there like normal.

Is there a delegate for the install prompt I can listen for? Or some way to quit the app when the install button is pressed?